# Button to generate specific .pdf template based on field

Tags: apex, visualforce, class

We have a .pdf generator setup on the quote object that generates the .pdf based on a visualforce page template.

When you click the "Generate .pdf" button on the quote object it initiates a simple visualforce page that calls the PDFCreateAttachController, see below:

```
public class PDFCreateAttachController {
    ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public Quote q {get;set;}


    public PDFCreateAttachController(ApexPages.StandardController c) {

        controller = c;
        q = (Quote) c.getRecord();
    }

    /* The action method that will generate a PDF document from the QuotePDF page and attach it to
   the quote provided by the standard controller. Called by the action binding for the attachQuote
   page, this will do the work and take the user back to the quote detail page. */
    public PageReference attachQuote() {
        /* Get the page definition */
        system.debug('BEGIN ATTACHQUOTE');
        PageReference pdfPage = Page.CustomQuote_CC;

        /* set the quote id on the page definition */
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',q.id);

        /* generate the pdf blob */
        Blob pdfBlob;

        // need the if else to handle the getContentAsPDF call from within a test....
        if(!test.isRunningTest())
        {
            pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
        }
        else
        {
            pdfBlob = blob.valueof('TEST');
        }


        /* create the quote document against the quote */
        quotedocument qd = new quotedocument();

        qd.document = pdfBlob;
        qd.quoteId = q.id;
        insert qd;

        string thisQuoteDocName = [Select Name FROM QuoteDocument WHERE Id = :qd.Id].Name;

        /* create the attachment against the Opportunity */
        /*Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = q.opportunityId, name=q.name + '.pdf', body = pdfBlob); */
        Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = q.opportunityId, name=thisQuoteDocName, body = pdfBlob);
        insert a;

        /* send the user back to the quote detail page */
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+q.id);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
        //return pdfPage;
    }


}
```

You can see that it references the CustomQuoteController_CC visualforce page for it's actual template for the quote. I'd like to create several quote templates that would be referenced by this apex controller, depending on a custom field in Opportunity called "Product" - Product_Type__c

For example, if the product is "Fruits" under the Opportunity, I would want to reference a custom quote VF Page that is setup for fruit when generating the .PDF. If the product under the Opportunity is "Vegetables" when I click the generate .pdf under the quote, it should reference a custom VF Page for vegatables. Hopefully that makes sense.

Any tips on how to best achieve this?

Comment: What if your opportunity has both fruit and vegetable?

Comment: You should aim to build a single VF page with conditionally rendered sections based on your custom  product type.